# ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.embedded.EmbeddedSolrServer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, solr, spring-data-solr

I'm using Spring Boot with the following dependency:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.data', 
name: 'spring-data-solr', 
version: '2.1.6.RELEASE'
```

For development and testing, I'd like to use the EmbeddedSolrServer.  For that, I have the following code.

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedSolrServerFactoryBean solrServerFactoryBean() {
    EmbeddedSolrServerFactoryBean factory = new EmbeddedSolrServerFactoryBean();
    factory.setSolrHome(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_SOLR_SOLR_HOME));
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public SolrTemplate solrTemplate() throws Exception {

    return new SolrTemplate(solrServerFactoryBean().getSolrClient(""));
}
```

When I run my code, I'm greeted with the following error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.embedded.EmbeddedSolrServer
```

I decided to inspect, and I see that the following package is nowhere to be found, with the "embedded" and "core" part being highlighted Red by Intellij when I inspect the EmbeddedSolrServerFactory source code.

```
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.embedded.EmbeddedSolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer;
```

To get around this, I've tried adding this dependency to my Gradle setup, but to no avail.

```
    compile group: 'org.apache.solr', name: 'solr-solrj', version: '5.5.2'
```

It's almost as if the EmbeddedSolrServer has been wiped from the map.  Does anyone know where I can get that class, or why my Spring Boot Solr setup isn't auto importing it?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Solr version Spring Boot uses is wrong. You can set it manually in your pom with:

```
<properties>
    <solr.version>5.5.2</solr.version>
</properties>
```

Hope this solves your problem.